# Error while running Spark java program

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to run spark standalone java program using Maven but facing issues while building the project as below.

Spark version: 
1.1.0
mvn clean package
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SimpleApp"

After running mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="SimpleApp" i am getting the below error.

```
[WARNING] Couldn't destroy threadgroup  org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$IsolatedThreadGroup[name=SimpleApp,maxpri=10]
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.destroy(ThreadGroup.java:754)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Comment: what if you don't use the exec plugin? does it work and are you able to run the JAR?

Comment: How can we directly run the jar?i tried using spark-submit but it failed with no class def error